# Telegram Bot - not able to send messages after around 24 hours

Tags: java, telegram-bot

I created a Telegram Bot and I added this bot to my Telegram application (not to a group)

I send a message to the bot so that I can get the chatID.

In my Java program I send a request to

```
 JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/getUpdates");
```

so I got the chatID

now I am able to send messages to Telegram so that I can read these messages on my mobile phone

```
  JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=" + config.getTelegramChat() + "&parse_mode=html&text=" + message);
```

this works fine but after around 24 hours Telegram will not receive any messages. It will continue receiving messages if I send a message from my phone to the bot. (without restarting my Java program)

Any idea ?

PS: My bot is only pushing infos to my phone

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean getUpdates only give you 24Hr ago messages?

You should write old updates into your database, not GET from Telegram server.

Reference: [Getting Updates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates)

Comment: No, I use getUpdated only 1 time to get the chat_id
After this my Java program send messages to the mobile phone via the bot, there is no user input on telephone site so no need to call getUpdates

The problem is that JAVA is not able to send messages after around 24 hours, if I send a message on the phone to the bot I get the messages again